# How to toggle xdebug on php alpine docker nginx

Tags: php, docker, nginx, xdebug, alpine-linux

I installed xdebug on alpine using docker. In the dockerfile I put

```
RUN apk add --no-cache $PHPIZE_DEPS \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.9.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug \
    && rm -r /tmp/pear
```

and this is the content of /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug 
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_autostart=0 
xdebug.remote_connect_back=off 
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal 
xdebug.remote_port=9005 
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM 
xdebug.max_nesting_level=1500
```

now if I run **php -v** from the command line I get

```
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2021 00:57:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.9.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2020, by Derick Rethans
```

and xdebug works within phpstorm. Great!

The problem is that I can't disable it.

if I comment out the first line in docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini and I run **kill -USR2 2** inside the container and then I run **php -v** I get

```
PHP 7.4.15 (cli) (built: Feb 18 2021 00:57:06) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

which is correct, but if I check phpinfo() from the browser I can see it still active and phpstorm is still receiving the connection and activating breakpoints.

I am uging nginx so I suspect I need to do something with it but I don't have experience with it so I don't know.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: Why don't you just stop debugging in phpstorm? There us a button for that. You can also use a cookie or a query param to toggle whether to start debugging or not.

Comment: because having xdebug active makes the server slow, so I'd prefer to enable it only when I need it.

Comment: In that case, you need to do the toggle in your ini and restart the container each time. I haven't tried setting xdebug options through `set_ini()` from php source code, but it's worth a try if you want to do it programmatically from your pho code.

Comment: 1) Check what PHP config file is used. On Linux it's very common to have separate php.ini for CLI (the `php -v`) and the one used by a web server. Check the `phpinfo()` output, the top table (do it in CLI and via web page) -- check what config files are loaded there.

Comment: 2) Xdebug v2 is no longer supported. I suggest you upgrade to Xdebug v3 -- it has many improvements (especially in configuring the needed functionality) including the impact that it does on PHP when it is enabled.

Comment: it is using the same xdebug.ini file. I think I just need a way to restart the web server, as doing kill -USR2 2 is just restarting the CLI. As I mentioned I am using nginx, so is that I need to restart? how to do it?

Comment: How to restart/reload config for nginx? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/basic-functionality/runtime-control/

Comment: I know where the doc is. I am looking for a way to restart nginx and reload the xdebug conf and just doing -s reload doesn't work. any other clever suggestion?

Comment: Do you use **php-fpm** (the common setup when using PHP with nginx)? If restarting nginx does not do it for you then you need to reload PHP service... Try this: https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm